# How do i get access back to my send grid account?

Tags: gcloud

How do i get access back to my send grid account?

I had send grid free account which i used google cloud "app launcher " to create it , i blocked my dynamic IP somehow by mistake , contacted send grid for support ,since i used g cloud to create the account they told to get in touch with google support which i can not afford as my trial period is finished .

send grid support respond 
"Hey there,
thanks for reaching out to us about your troubles logging in. Unfortunately because your account is held through Google. you are gonna have to get in contact with them to be able to regain access. sorry for the confusion."

Answer (score 0):

Basically had to remove the billing account ,create new one instead and sign up for the Send Grid using same email but different user name .